# SSIS Combine Multiple Columns into one with nulls

Tags: sql, ssis

I know similar questions have been asked before, however I have a unique case that is not solved by the previous answers.

I have a Database rows that has 5 comment columns that I would like to combine into one.
Example:

```
    ID     NAME    CMT1     CMT2    CMT3    CMT 4   CMT5
    1    John     BLAH     BLAH    null    null    null
    2    Mary     BLAH     null    null    null    null
    3    Sue      BLAH     BLAH    BLAH    BLAH    BLAH
```

I would like to see the following:

```
    ID      NAME    CombinedComment
    1       John    BLAH BLAH
    2       Mary    BLAH
    3       Sue     BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH
```

Now for the caveats.

```
1. I cannot use SQL to join the data. The data comes from a linked server via a stored procedure. This is the usual response to this problem.
2. I cannot modify the stored procedure.
3. I am using a Derived Column and using the following:

    Combined      CMT1 + " " + CMT2  + " " + CMT3  + " " + CMT4  + " " + CMT5

This works only for rows that have a value in ALL 5 comment fields.
```

So to summarize, I would want the Combined Comment column to work for all rows even if there is null in the other comment fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Derived column transform use

```
ISNULL(CMT1)? "":CMT1
```

OR

```
REPLACENULL(CMT1,"")
```

around the comment fields.

Comment: How would I do this so I get all 5 columns?

ISNULL(CMT1) ? "":CMT1 + " " + ISNULL(CMT2) ? "":CMT2 ...?

Comment: I think ReplaceNULL would work best for you. So -- REPLACENULL(CMT1, "") + " " + REPLACENULL(CMT2, "") + " " + REPLACENULL(CMT3, "") + " " + REPLACENULL(CMT4, "") + " " + REPLACENULL(CMT5, "")

Comment: Looks like ReplaceNull would have resolved my problem but it is not available in ssis 2008 :(

I used the Isnull(cmt1)?"":CMT1 like you example before but still it did not work. I did enclose them in (). like (Isnull(cmt1)?"":CMT1) and used your replacenull example and it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: Then stick to Conditional on ISNULL  - ISNULL(CMT1)? "":CMT1  + " " + ISNULL(CMT2)? "":CMT2  + " " + ISNULL(CMT3)? "":CMT3  + " " + ISNULL(CMT4)? "":CMT4  + " " + ISNULL(CMT5)? "":CMT5

Comment: I used something similar to what you put, just had ( ) around each IsNull.  (ISNULL(CMT1)? "":CMT1) + " " + (ISNULL(CMT2)? "":CMT2) + " " + (ISNULL(CMT3)? "":CMT3) + " " + (ISNULL(CMT4)? "":CMT4) + " " + (ISNULL(CMT5)? "":CMT5). again thanks.